# Maven error messages do not link to code

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, maven, build, compiler-errors

I checked out the Google guice library and imported the projects as Maven projects in eclipse Kepler. All went well.

When I run Run As > Maven test

One test fails

```
Failed tests: 
  testInterceptingNonBridgeWorks(com.google.inject.MethodInterceptionTest).

And the link points to a text file that opens in the editor contains a bunch of exception messages such as 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.google.inject.MethodInterceptionTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 10, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.043 sec <<< FAILURE!
testInterceptingNonBridgeWorks(com.google.inject.MethodInterceptionTest)  Time elapsed: 0.01 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<1> but was:<0>
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:57)
    at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:329)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:78)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:234)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:241)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals(TestCase.java:409)
    at com.google.inject.MethodInterceptionTest.testInterceptingNonBridgeWorks(MethodInterceptionTest.java:271)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
```

My question is - Is there a way to have such build errors directly link to code line numbers in a maven project just the way normal Java nature project would work ?

Debasish

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, just run as junit test, and you will get the proper support in the JUnit panes. Otherwise, tracking back from the failure stacktrace, you can easily see where it fails:

```
at com.google.inject.MethodInterceptionTest.testInterceptingNonBridgeWorks(MethodInterceptionTest.java:271)
```

Open the file with ctrl-shift-T -> MIT

locate the error with ctrl-L -> 271

Comment: I am bit perplexed as to why a direct link is not possible from the maven messages. Is there no way to achieve this ? Since it quite a pain for large set of multi module projects to locate the source file from the error / exception messages

Comment: Maven is a command line tool and outputs on a standard console. You cannot write a link in a console pane.

Comment: Eclipse, on the other hand may enhance the output and place markers on lines to pinpoint sources, but that is eclipse.

Comment: The run as -> Maven test, is provided by an eclipse plugin, that will capture the maven console and present it.

Comment: Which was why I suggested the run as -> unit test, which uses the eclipse JUnit plugin. It will be the same tests, but different eclipse plugins..

Comment: The challenge is when you are importing a large project and running its tests or compiling it to get started. I get what you mean but my point is technically it should be possible to link the maven tool output to eclipse artifacts.. isn't it ?

Comment: I tried right-clicking on a project, and selecting run-as -> maven test. The console showed me the maven output, and class names and stacktraces were automatically turned into links. Wasn't that what you needed? I'm using the m2e feature, which seems to do it automatically.

Comment: thats precisely what I am struggling with . It doesn't hyperlink any of them in the error output

Comment: Out of curiousity. It may not take that long to download a new eclipse and install in a separate location add m2e and a sample maven project with test as.